# Why Single(IEnumerable<T>,Predicate<T>) is so inefficient

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, base-class-library

code from .Net references

```
    public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
      if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      if (predicate == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
      TSource source1 = default (TSource);
      long num = 0L;
      foreach (TSource source2 in source)
      {
        if (predicate(source2))
        {
          source1 = source2;
          checked { ++num; }
        }
      }
      switch (num)
      {
        case 0L:
          throw Error.NoMatch();
        case 1L:
          return source1;
        default:
          throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch();
      }
    }
```

so question is: why not throw an exception just if there are more than one element that matches? So for example, if we have a big collection we can get a big perfomance problem. Why not write a simple `if` in code? Example:

```
public static class LinqTester
{
    public static TSource MySingle<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (predicate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
        TSource result = default(TSource);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (TSource value in source)
        {
            if (predicate(value))
            {
                checked { ++count; }
                if (count > 1)
                    throw new Exception("MoreThanOneMatch");
                result = value;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
            throw new Exception("NoMatch");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new byte[100000000];

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr.Single(i => i == 0));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sw.Stop();
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }


        var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr.MySingle(i => i == 0));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sw2.Stop();
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sw2.Elapsed);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Difference = {0}", (double) sw.ElapsedTicks/sw2.ElapsedTicks);

    }
```

results:

http://ideone.com/A62JOn

I rewrote original Single because mono has another realisation just 3.5x times slower.

Comment: what are the results ?

Comment: And when you post your results please do it in release mode without a debugger attached.

Comment: Ran the test in Release, without debugger on my machine: 798ms for "Single", 0ms for "MySingle"

Comment: I think the question should be answerable from just looking at the code. It could easily short-circuit out of the loop but doesn't. Why not?

Comment: To summarize the answer in the linked duplicate "Doing it this way optimizes the success case where `Single()` would not throw a exception. The designers decided to optimize for success instead of optimizing for failure.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's not slower than a simple `Single()` because in normal case `if` statement will be checked only once for single element that matches. And there is no sence why `Single(IEnumerable<T>)` has enchanced perfomance, but `Single(IEnumerable<T>,Predicate<T>)` - hasn't